# why nodejs is not respecting the memory limits set in pm2 ecosystem file

Tags: node.js, memory, pm2

I am trying to configure nodejs to use only 512 MB of ram memory. Here is my ecosystem config file

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [{
   script: './app.js',
   watch: true,
   instances: "max",
   exec_mode  : "cluster",
   ignore_watch : ["node_modules"],
   "node_args": "--max_old_space_size=512",
   }]
};
```

and here is the pm2 script in package.json

```
"scripts": {
"start": "env-cmd -f ./Config/dev.env pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --no-daemon",
"dev": "env-cmd -f ./Config/dev.env nodemon start app.js",
"debug": "env-cmd -f ./Config/dev.env node --inspect app.js"
}
```

When I run my code using npm run start. And I check my memory of using free -m command I can see that I am using 750 MB of ram memory

Comment: `max_old_space_size` seems to just limit how much unused memory node will keep around. If you are actively using memory, `max_old_space_size` will not limit this.

Comment: so is there is a way to limit node js memory usage.

Comment: Looks like `pm2` has a way to kill the process and restart if it goes over a limit: https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/memory-limit/

Comment: A VM could be used for this.

Comment: Could you elaborate further. how can I use VM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to use
--max-memory-restart instead of --max_old_space_size either in your echo system or command line arguments